# I want my brother and mother to move to Australia

Tags: visa, immigration, australia

I need some guidance. I am a German citizen and have been in Australia for almost 3 years. Last year, I received my partner visa; I have an Australian wife and 2 kids.

I want to bring my brother and mother to live with me and, for him, to go to school. He is 9 years old and my mother is 52. Both are German citizens.

**What visa would they need to be eligible to stay and live with me ?**

Comment: Can you elaborate? What visas have you looked at? Have you done any reseaerch yourself? Would you be providing for them or would your mum work? Etc. The more detail, the more useful answers can be...

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after you asked the question, the Australian Government introduced a [parent category visas](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Brin/Pare).

> On Friday 5 May 2017, the Government announced the introduction of the new temporary sponsored parent visa for parents of Australians during the 2017–18 Migration Programme year. The new visa will allow Australians to sponsor their parents to stay in Australia for up to five years at a time.
>
> For more information see: [Introducing the temporary sponsored parent visa](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visi/temporary-sponsored-visa-parents)
>
> You might be eligible to apply for a parent category visa if:
>
> - you have a child who is an Australian citizen, an Australian permanent resident, or an eligible New Zealand citizen
> - your child has been living in Australia lawfully for at least 2 years before you lodge your visa application
> - you have a sponsor
> - you meet the Balance of family test criteria
> - you meet health and character requirements.
>
> **How long can I stay in Australia on a parent category visa**?
>
> A parent category visa allows you to:
>
> - live in Australia for up to 2 years as a temporary resident, or
> - live in Australia as an Australian permanent resident.

While this category makes no mention of inclusion of minor children, a visa for your brother may be included as Family Member or a [child whom you're sponsoring](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Brin/Chil#).